# Displaying image based on string chosen?

Tags: android, arrays, string, image, random

I have a code rite now that just generates a random drink combination from an array, what I need to do is have a different image assigned to each choice and have it display that image. 
Here is my code for a random drink:

```
    if(Vodka.equals(true)){
                final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2);
                randomIndex = random.nextInt(array_city.Vodka.length);
                text2.setText(array_city.Vodka[randomIndex]);
            }
```

Say this code spits out "Smirnof" then i display a picture of the bottle, it spits out "Sky" then changes to a picture of that bottle.  How would i do this without making an if statement for each option, my arrays are very long and that would be alot of if statements i was just Hoping that there is an easier way to do it?
Thanks anybody for your help! it is very much appreciated I have been stuck on this for a while.

===============================================================
@Joan

Here is what i am trying to put together using your code:

```
    //Run option Vodka
            if(Vodka.equals(true)){
                final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2);
                randomIndex = random.nextInt(array_city.Vodka.length);
                text2.setText(array_city.Vodka[randomIndex]);

                final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                int Cimage = getResources().getIdentifier(array_city.Vodka[randomIndex], null, "com.famousmods.what.should.i.drink");
                image.setImageResource(Cimage);
            }
```

Here is what my array looks like (a smaller example):

```
    public static final String[] Vodka = {"Absolut Vodka","Finlandia","Ketel One","Polmos Krakow","Skyy","smirnoff vodka",
    "Stolichnaya","Fleischmann's","Gilbey's","Gordon's","Wolfschmitt","Five-O-Clock"};
```

I have put the file "smirnoff_vodka.png" into my res/drawables as an example but it doesnt work?

Comment: How do you load the images? How do you know the path of the image? Please provide more code.

Comment: @nkr if i understand correctly what your asking all the images will be stored locally within the app? i dont have a directory or anything set up yet

Comment: So you did not code anything of the image loading yet?

Comment: @nkr no, The only way I knew of to do so would be to make hundreds of if statements for each choice in the array, I know there has to be a simpler way and I am still fairly new to android programming. Thats why I made this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getResources().getIdentifier("image_name", null, "your_application_package");` on your context to retrieve the image id. Then you can use this id as you would use `R.id.image_name`.

EDIT: It needs to be "drawable" instead of null. See below.

Comment: im sorry but i still really new to this and am still confused, is there anyway you could explain with more detail? It would really help out alot

Comment: If you want to avoid a big `switch` statement, you have to define a convention and automatically find the appropriate image using its name. For example, name your bottle images _bottle1.png_, _bottle2.png_, _bottle3.png_. Note that _1_, _2_, and _3_ should match the index of the names of these bottles in your `array_city` array.
This way, you can retrieve the identifier of the corresponding image using `int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("bottle"+i, null, "your_application_package")`, and update the ImageView using `imageView.setImageResource(id)`.

Comment: Use : `getResources().getIdentifier("img"+randomIndex,null, "com.famousmods.what.should.i.drink");`

and call your image `img1.png`

Comment: i renamed the image "img1" and this is what the rest of the code looks like    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                 int Cimage = getResources().getIdentifier("img"+randomIndex, null, "com.famousmods.what.should.i.drink");
                 text2.setText(Cimage);
                 image.setImageResource(Cimage);
                }     It is still not displaying the image?

Comment: I haven't tested it but here's some suggestions :  
- Rename `img1` to `img1.png`.  
- Is your image in `res/drawable` folder ?  
- Check the value of `randomIndex`, consider forcing it to `1`.  
- Replace `context.getResources().getIdentifier("bottle"+i, null, "your_application_package")` with `context.getResources().getIdentifier("bottle"+i, "drawable", context.getPackageName())`.  
- Check what `getIdentifier` returns.